# Handling redirects correctly with NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, redirect, nsurlconnection

For the purposes of this, I'm going to pretend the original url is `http://host/form` and the new url is `https://host/form`. (Note that before I ship this, both URLs are going to be secure. However, the nonsecure-to-secure seems like a convenient redirect to test this on.)

I'm accessing a web API using `NSURLConnection` that redirects me. Basically, I want to take everything I just submitted to `http://hostaform` and re-submit it to `https://host/form`. I thought this would be the default behavior, but it looks like the body is being lost in the redirect.

So I think I need to handle the `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` event of the `NSURLConnection`'s delegate and re-attach the body. The problem is this message seems woefully underdocumented. The only info I can find on this method is  **NSURLConnection Class Reference**, which isn't very helpful. Among other things, it includes this:

> *redirectResponse*: The URL response that caused the redirect. May be nil in cases where this method is not being sent as a result of involving the delegate in redirect processing.

I'm not sure what this means. Combined with an initial `willSendRequest:` invocation, I think this is means `willSendRequest:` is being sent even for my initial request, prior to the redirect response. Is that correct?

So I've added code to my delegate to retain the body an extra time, and added this `willSendRequest:` handler:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection *)inConnection
             willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)inRequest
            redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *)inRedirectResponse;
{
    if (inRedirectResponse) {
        NSMutableURLRequest *r = [[inRequest mutableCopy] autorelease];
        [r setURL: [inRedirectResponse URL]];
        [r setHTTPBody: body];
        return r;
    } else {
        return inRequest;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. But I'm not even sure if this is the right approach. It seems excessively hackish to me. What should I be doing? Is this documented anywhere? I've found nothing useful in Apple's documentation or using Google so far.

(This is on the iPhone, although there doesn't seem to be much difference in these classes.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There's a note in [section 10.3.2 of RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.2) about this behaviour:

> Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after
> receiving a 301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents
> will erroneously change it into a GET request.

So this behaviour seems to be non-standard but historical. That `GET` request is not a `POST`, and it'll be missing the payload.

Interestingly enough, this is also in the same section:

> If the 301 status code is received in response to a request other
> than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
> request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
> change the conditions under which the request was issued.

That's pretty clear and seems to indicate we can't fix this, but I think ignoring this for the purpose of our own web service clients for services we pick (or control) is probably the least bad alternative.

So how do we solve this?

Instead of the `willSendResponse:` in the original question, I'm using this:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection
             willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)request
            redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse;
{
    if (redirectResponse) {
        // we don't use the new request built for us, except for the URL
        NSURL *newURL = [request URL];
        // Previously, store the original request in _originalRequest.
        // We rely on that here!
        NSMutableURLRequest *newRequest = [_originalRequest mutableCopy];
        [newRequest setURL: newURL];
        return newRequest;
    } else {
        return request;
    }
}
```

The idea here is that instead of cloning the new request and trying to shape it the same as the one Cocoa Touch sends me, I create a clone of the original request and change just the URL to match the request Cocoa Touch sent me. That original request is still a `POST` with the payload attached.

If you control the server, it's worth reading [RFC 2616, section 10.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3) in its entirety to see if there's a better code you can use (while checking, of course, that iOS handles the better code as it should).

You could also make a mutable copy of the redirected request and replace its HTTP method with the HTTP method of the original request. Same general principle, though that would favour keeping things from the new request rather than the old. In some circumstances that might work better, but I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: You said "Instead of willSendResponse:", but there is no such thing in URLConnection.  Your answer seems similar to what you have above, except you are sending the URL to the original?  And you are referencing request in your mutableCopy, which is not declared anywhere.  The answer is very confusing.

Comment: willSendResponse is a part of the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate protocol. mutableCopy is a method built in to NSURLRequest. And what I'm doing is throwing away the new request that NSURLConnection has created, and re-using my original request (copied, with just the URL changed).

Comment: Well that was a pointlessly wasted afternoon. Cheers for the solution, this saved my sanity :)

Comment: I don't suppose there's a version of this for synchronous connections?

Comment: Well, the real answer to that is never use synchronous connections. Never. Even if you think you have a good reason, it isn't good enough for your app to crash due it. And crash it will.

Comment: I wanted to point out that by copying the original request, the original headers are copied which includes the authorization header. For me, my original request required basic authentication but the redirect request did not require any authentication so I had to be a little more judicious about copying the original request. The result was a 400 level error.

Comment: I've looked at the request parameter under iOS 8.1 and the HTTP Method does indeed get changed to GET. I wonder why Apple would implement such erroneous behaviour. Anyway, good to know about this. Thanks!

Comment: I assume it dates back to some NSDate in history, if you know what I mean. :) That note might very well have been written about NextStep, and the behaviour just stayed all the way to iOS.

Comment: @TPoschel: Added a note about that to the answer. I'll have to try it a few times before I recommend it, but it seems sound. :)

Comment: There's a very good reason for this.  Many websites respond to a POST by redirecting URLs to another location, and you wouldn't want to redo the POST to that new URL, because you'd be uploading the data to a page/script that doesn't care about it.  In the rare situations where you need to redirect the actual POST request, use a 307 code.

Comment: Per the RFC, this behaviour is counter-spec.

Answer (score 13):

You should be checking the HTTP response status code sent by the server to determine whether to send a GET or repeat the POST. For 303 (or 302), send a GET request. For 307, repeat the POST.

Comment: Upticked for technical correctness. This is the right thing to do in a web browser, and the right thing to do theoretically, but it's the wrong thing to do pointing at a web service written in PHP. You're probably signing in to a service, and falling over to a GET means you're dropping the payload that would sign you in.

Comment: Read new RFC. You're more correct than I realized; if you can control the server, changing to a 307 is a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem with redirecting. 
Thanks to AJSoaks! 
I tried as he suggested and the problem is resolved.

So, i was trying to post the username and password through the POST method, and i saw that server redirected my request. As AJSoaks says, in case if there is 302 error you should repeat the request but this time using GET method instead of previous POST.

... at some point you have the following lines:
... it can be inside if your IBAction (button pressed) method or wherever you want...

```
NSMutableString *postString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[postString appendString:@"username=YourUsername&password=YourPassword"];

    //the original URL (https means that it supports SSL protocol)
    //it doesn't change anything, don't worry about it
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://loginWebpageURL"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

[postString release];
[request release];
```

Than you should also implement the redirect NSURLConnection delegate method, with the following signature:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
            willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
           redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
```

inside of this method, in case if you have SERVER's Error 302 or 303 you should implement something similar to the code bellow, just copy the code that you see and replace it with the new URL (redirected). The new URL you can see in the browser or if you want it is very useful, also in the future, checking it with Firebug (Firefox plugin) or Safari WEB INSPECTOR. If you use Firebug all information you can find under the "Net" option:

```
if (redirectResponse) {

    NSLog(@"REDIRECT");
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestTmp = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://areaclienti.tre.it/selfcare/areaclienti133/4552_infoCosti_ITA_HTML.xsl"]];

    return [requestTmp autorelease];
}

//return original request in case thay there is no redirecting...
else return request;
```

Comment: Thank you,your codes gave me an complete explanation to this issue,Thanks a lot. But I have some sugguestions: The newly created `requestTmp` request should be assigned with a HTTP method,`GET` for example:  `[requestTmp setHTTPMethod:@"GET"]`

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection does not add the originalRequest headers into the redirected request in the "willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)inRequest".

You can workaround this problem by adding "originalRequest.headers" into the redirected request.