# connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse example prject

Tags: iphone, web-services, uiwebview, html-parsing

Could anyone provide me with one please?

.h

```
 #import "UntitledViewController.h"

 @implementation UntitledViewController



 - (id)init 
 {
self = [super init];
if (self) 
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tinyurl.com/a3cx"];
    [self loadTinyURL:url];
}
return self;
```

}

```
- (void)loadTinyURL:(NSURL *)url 
{
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request 
                                                              delegate:self];
if (!connection) 
    NSLog(@"could not connect with: %@", url);
else {
    NSLog(@"this works");
}

}


  - (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
         willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
        redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
  {
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

// http statuscodes between 300 & 400 is a redirect ...
if (response && statusCode >= 300 && statusCode < 400) 
    NSLog(@"redirecting to : %@", [request URL]);

return request;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSURLConnection samplecode based on either asynchronous or synchronous from apple website.you can know why we use this delegate method through the [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446509/handling-redirects-correctly-with-nsurlconnection)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link I have tried doing that but it isn't working for some reason I will be updating by question with my code for .h and .m please help me out in this

Comment: did you inherit delegate method for NSURLConnection,what is your problem,u have given code only..did you put break point in the method to check whether it calls or not