# Why doesn't NSURLConnection's currentRequest indicate the correct URL after redirection?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, ios5

By my reading of the docs for `NSURLConnection`, the `currentRequest` method should reflect any redirection that may have occurred while loading:

> As the connection performs the load, the request may change as a result of protocol canonicalization or due to following redirects. This method is be used to retrieve the current value.

However, when I inspect the `currentRequest` in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` it always has the URL of the original request, even though examining the response data shows that the redirection completed successfully. (see contrived example below)

My question is this: why doesn't `currentRequest` return the actual current request? Am I doing something wrong or is this expected behavior? If this *is* the expected behavior then what is `currentRequest` supposed to be useful for?

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *connection;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    return YES;
}

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"willSendRequest // request: %@ // currentRequest: %@", request, [connection currentRequest]);
    return request;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"didFinishLoading // originalRequest: %@ // currentRequest: %@", [connection originalRequest], [connection currentRequest]);
}

@end
```

Running this example gives me the following output:

```
2012-12-18 15:18:44.949 ConnectionTest[12534:c07] willSendRequest // request: <NSURLRequest http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html> // currentRequest: <NSURLRequest http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html>
2012-12-18 15:18:44.954 ConnectionTest[12534:c07] willSendRequest // request: <NSURLRequest http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/Overview.html> // currentRequest: <NSURLRequest http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html>
2012-12-18 15:18:44.955 ConnectionTest[12534:c07] didFinishLoading // originalRequest: <NSURLRequest http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html> // currentRequest: <NSURLRequest http://jigsaw.w3.org/HTTP/300/301.html>
```

My expectation is that the last call to `currentRequest` would show the page URL ending in `Overview.html`, but instead it still shows `301.html`.

Comment: I'd report this as a bug.  Either the documentation is wrong or the code is.  My vote is that the code is given that there are both `originalRequest` and `currentRequest` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm just going to chalk this one up to Apple having to confusing documentation. I can get the final request URL by examining the response object, but to me something called `currentRequest` should reflect the last request made after there's been a redirection.

Comment: What about HTTP headers? For me they differ in contents for original and current requests.

Answer (score 2):

How does the redirection occur? Is the http server returning a redirect status?

The original URL request is probably not a mutable one and because of this the system cannot modify the URL.

You would have to make a new request for each redirection as explained by the answer here: [Handling redirects correctly with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446509/handling-redirects-correctly-with-nsurlconnection)

You get the final URL not from the connection, but from the response object. See for example this URL unshortener I made: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/mine-is-longer-than-yours/

Comment: That question is about a different problem. The redirection itself works fine (the example URL is a test page that responds with a 301 status). You don't need to modify the original request, as per the docs: "The delegate may return request unmodified to allow the redirect", which is exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: Let me clarify: if you do not modify the request then the URL will stay the same. Apple does not modify it and it would be unexpected behavior for developers that a property of an immutable object would change. If you need the final URL you need to get it from the NSHTTPURLResponse or modify the redirection request as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Iphone Developper (just Mac), but it seems like most NSURLConnectionDelegate methods have been deprecated in iOS5, and NSURLDownload (and its delegate) seems to be the new way to do this : [NSURLConnectionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connection%3adidReceiveResponse%3a) [NSURLDownloadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLDownloadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLDownloadDelegate)

Comment: `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` is actually declared in [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html), which is new in iOS 5. Confusingly it shares the same signature as one of the deprecated methods.