# NSURLConnection connection: didReceiveData: is not called after redirect

Tags: objective-c, ios, redirect, nsurlconnection

I am starting a request which gives me back HTML with a redirection inside. Why is the didReceiveData function not called a second time? I am trying to download a JSON File. (Using iOS6)

```
    - (void) testdownload{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://***];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d{

        NSString *tmpdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"data: %@", tmpdata);
    }
```

When i use a UIWebView the redirection will be handled and the JSON file will be shown. Playing with this function didn't work:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse{
    return request;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446509/handling-redirects-correctly-with-nsurlconnection

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code instead:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection *)inConnection
             willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)inRequest
            redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *)inRedirectResponse;
{
    if (inRedirectResponse) {
        NSMutableURLRequest *r = [[request mutableCopy] autorelease]; // original request
        [r setURL: [inRequest URL]];
        return r;
    } else {
        return inRequest;
    }
}
```

[Learn more on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446509/handling-redirects-correctly-with-nsurlconnection)

Comment: thx, but i tried this stuff before and it is still not working. The "willSendRequest" function is called two times before the "didreceiveData" function is called. Is this correct?

Comment: @tuvok Im not so sure, checkout the linked alternative question for more info

Comment: I think the problem is that the html page redirect with this:
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2"...

Answer (score 0):

I used this now instead (but not realy nice):

```
- (IBAction)redirectTest:(id)sender {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://billstclair.com/html-redirect.html"];
        _request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectNull];
        webview.delegate = self;
        [webview loadRequest:_request];
        [self.view addSubview:webview];

    }


    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

        NSString *content = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML"];
        NSLog(@"content: %@",content);
    }
```