# Detect HTTP code 302 from webView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I need to detect HTTP code 302 after the user introduces the correct login and password, I'm using this method:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
 didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"connection:didReceiveResponse");

    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

        int status = [httpResponse statusCode];

        if (status == 302) {

            //do something here
        }

        else
        {

            NSLog(@"http status code: %d", status);
        }

        [connection cancel]; 

    }

}
```

However I can only get status code 200 after the page is redirected, any idea please??

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using a webView should you be using this method? Is this not a `NSURLConnection` delegate method not a webView method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `UIWebView` then you need to check the error code within the delegate method of `UIWebViewDelegate`, not in the `didReceiveResponse` of `NSURLConnectionDelegate`.

this is the exact method where you can check the error code..

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    if (error.code == ERROR_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK {
       //do what you want to do here 
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

in case you are using `NSURLConnection` then answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446509/handling-redirects-correctly-with-nsurlconnection) might help your cause

Comment: you are right @AndreasLey,  in that case he need to resend the request by checking the error code in the `-(NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse` methid