# Handling POST redirects with block-based NSURLConnection API

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, redirect

I have to solve the problem that NSURLConnection automatically redirects POST redirects with a 302 response as GET requests (and drops the HTTP body and some headers).

I found and successfully tried the NSURLConnectionDataDelegate solution (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446509/handling-redirects-correctly-with-nsurlconnection?rq=1)), implementing:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
```

and throwing away/fixing the problematic request. This works.

However. As I understand it, this means I have to use the delegate APIs like:

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Is there a way to fix the redirect using the much more comfortable block-based asynchronous API as well?:

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```