# Retrieving JSON data behind HTTPS and login redirect pages

Tags: ios, iphone, django, json

I'm building an app that will (among other things) retrieve JSON data from a website that I built (I built the website using the Django framework). The entire website requires login credentials to gain access to anything. I set up a URL on the web server for testing that simply spits out some JSON data. My goal (at this point) is simply to access that JSON data from my app.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to connect to the URL, it fails since the web server redirects the app to the login page. I'm not sure how to send the credentials to the web server so that it doesn't re-direct to the login page but, instead, simply sends back the JSON  data. In the future, I hope to do this in reverse - send data back to the server via JSON.

Here's what I have going so far. Again, I'm new to iOS to pardon the potential ugliness of this code:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:www.mysite.com/test_json/"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                     timeoutInterval:30.0];

NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"garfonzo"
                                                                password:@"MyPassword"
                                                                persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
        NSLog(@"credential created");
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"previous authentication failure");
    }
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    // This is where we do stuff with the data received
    NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", strData);

    NSError *e = nil;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

    if (!jsonArray) {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
    } else {
        for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
            NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to see what `strData` was that was received and, sure enough, it was the HTML of the login webpage. So I know I'm at least making contact, but failing due to the redirect.

Any thoughts? Ideas for doing this correctly? Am I way off on my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a round about way of managing this. Instead of trying to handle credentials in the Objective-C code, I simply send the credentials on the end of the URL as part of a GET request. The URL now looks like this:

`NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mysite.com/test_json/?username='USERNAME'&password='PASSWORD'"];`

Now, to prevent my web server from redirecting to the login page (and since I'm using Django and have full control of the web server) I created a middleware to handle the above url. My custom middleware has this in it:

```
    if request.path != '/accounts/login/' and request.user.is_anonymous():
         url = request.path.split('/')[1]
         if url == 'test_json':
             username = request.GET['username']
             password = request.GET['password']
             user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
             if user is not None:
                 if user.is_active:
                     login(request, user)
```

This way I can have my web server handle any request from my app (which, in the future, will always have a URL base of `mysite.com/m/ios/...`) differently. It will assume the credentials are in the URL. In production, this is all handled over `HTTPS` so there will be encryption present.

Hopefully this helps someone else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

The following link may be of help to you:
[Handling Redirects and Other Request Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/urlloadingsystem/Articles/RequestChanges.html)

Also, you can explore the delegate method :

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection: (NSURLConnection *)inConnection
             willSendRequest: (NSURLRequest *)inRequest
            redirectResponse: (NSURLResponse *)inRedirectResponse;
```

Take a look at this link
: [Handling redirects correctly with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1446509/667586)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I had looked at those links but couldn't quite pin down the solution for my specific situation. As often is the case with posting to SO, shortly after posting my question, I figured out a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)wsLooking{
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example?data=example"]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

-(void)fetchedData:(NSData*)responseData {

    if (responseData) {

        NSError *error     = nil;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];
        NSLog(@"%@",json);
    }
}
```

You can download source code from [this](https://github.com/henry434343/iOS_JSONParse) that is code for parse json from http website