# "Too many HTTP redirects" from iOS to Apache/JBoss Server

Tags: ios, apache, jboss, nsurlconnection

We have a major problem with "Too many HTTP redirects" connection error. The problem occurs only when the connection is made through a mobile network (wi-fi works fine).

What we have is an Apache server which gets the requests and then it connects to JBoss to fetch the data.

If the server is restarted the problem is not present for a while but soon it occurs again. What is interesting is that the Android app doesn't have the problem, it happens only with the iOS app.

I tried this solution - [Handling redirects correctly with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446509/handling-redirects-correctly-with-nsurlconnection) but it doesn't help.